# There is an error of exception in thread "main" and i need to have a message entered

Tags: java

I don't see the issue or how to input the message. The full error that I keep getting is below. I can't see any problems with the code and I can't find a way to a message into the code.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of ran
ge: 30
    at java.base/java.lang.StringLatin1.charAt (String.java:47)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.charAt (String.java:693
    at Main.main (Main.java:15)
```

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("What is your message? ");
        String message ="" + "\n";

        System.out.println("\nYour message is " +  " characters long.");
        System.out.println("The first character is at position 0 and is '" +  "'.");
        int lastpos = 30;
        System.out.println("The last character is at position " + lastpos + " and is '" + message.charAt(lastpos) + "'.");
        System.out.println("\nHere are all the characters, one at a time:\n");

        for ( int i=0; i<message.length(); i++ )
        {
            System.out.println("\t" + i + " - '" + message.charAt(i) + "'");
        }

        int a_count = 0;

        for ( int i=0; i<message.length(); i++ )
        {
            char letter = message.charAt(i);
            if ( letter == 'a' || letter == 'A' );
            {
                a_count++;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("\nYour message contains the letter 'a' " + a_count + " times. Isn't that interesting?");

    }
}
```

Comment: Your error is caused by 'message.charAt(lastpos)'. You've defined message to be a one-character string, but defined lastpos to be 30. This causes the exception.

Answer (score 0):

You never actually capture a message from the scanner - something like this:

```
message = kb.nextLine();
```

In addition, if you're trying to get the last index/position of the message, you'd want to do something like this:

```
int lastpos = message.length();
OR
int lastpos = message.length()-1;
```

The difference between the two being that the first gives you the size of the string, and the second gives you the last index of the string (for example, "abcdefg", lastpos 1 would be 7, and lastpos 2 would be 6).

Finally, keep in mind, you can do something like

```
message.charAt(0);
```

to get the first index character of the string.

Answer (score 0):

I have made 3 changes from the code that you have written. They are the following:

1. Read the message using `kb.nextLine();` instead of `"" + "\n";`
2. The first character of the message is `message.charAt(0)` instead of `"'."`
3. To count the number of characters, you have given semicolon after the if condition. Remove that. The semicolon after `if` is not needed.

Check the snippet below for better understanding.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("What is your message? ");
        String message = kb.nextLine();

        System.out.println("\nYour message is " + " characters long.");
        System.out.println("The first character is at position 0 and is '" + message.charAt(0));
        int lastpos = 30;
        System.out.println("The last character is at position " + lastpos + " and is '" + message.charAt(lastpos) + "'.");
        System.out.println("\nHere are all the characters, one at a time:\n");

        for (int i = 0; i < message.length(); i++) {
            System.out.println("\t" + i + " - '" + message.charAt(i) + "'");
        }

        int a_count = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < message.length(); i++) {
            char letter = message.charAt(i);
            if (letter == 'a' || letter == 'A') {
                a_count++;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("\nYour message contains the letter 'a' " + a_count + " times. Isn't that interesting?");

    }
}
```